# $(window).load returns function not defined when called from external .js file

Tags: jquery

I have a main.js external file where I implemented:

```
function initialize() {
...
}
```

and a main.php file where I call:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./main.js"></script>
```

then I call:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  initialize();
}
```

I know window.load fires code AFTER everything is loaded and ready.

Why does it return `ReferenceError: initialize is not defined`?

**EDIT:** Here it's my code in samplest form:

```
// # main.js.php file

<?php 
session_start();
include_once("include/functions.php"); 
session_write_close();

?>

var elements = [];

var element = { 
    container: "",
    visible: false,

    init : function(div) {
    ....
    }
};

function initialize() {
    elements.push(element.initialize("mydiv")); 
}


// # main.php file
<?php
session_start();
include_once("include/functions.php"); 
include_once("include/db_engine.php"); 

session_write_close();
}
?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/stile.css" media="all" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./main.js.php"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 

        $(window).load(function() {
              initialize();
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mydiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Most likely you didn't declare initialize globally.

Comment: Can we see the content of `main.js`? I suspect @KevinB is correct and the `initialize` function isn't globally scoped.

Comment: Also keep an eye out for something else on the page overwriting your `initialize()` function - that is a pretty common name afterall.

Comment: Have you tried $(document).ready() instead of $(window).load() ?

Comment: `main.js.php`....is that a copy-paste error? If not should that not be `main.js` ?

Comment: no, it's a php-js mixed file...I already used so

Comment: @Luigino: I see, so when you said you have a main.js external file loaded like this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="./main.js"></script>` that is not realy true. You are loading another `php` file which contains javascript inside it not an actual external js file.

Comment: Can you sure what is in your main.js? You don't have to show us main.js.php, just what is generated and sent to the browser.

Comment: (window).load() fires earlier than (document).load() so maybe your js is not loaded when calling the function, as the error says! you can check this out via console.log('filename') to know when is what ready to fire.

Comment: @codelio that can't be the case. His `main.js.php` reference comes before the call to `$(window).load(...)` and is not async so that script MUST have executed by the time the even handler is even registered.

Comment: just a typing error in function initialize() `(element.init("mydiv"))` works fine here

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK solved by myself.. it was a typo around echoing some PHP variables from cookies... thanks anyway to all :-) BTW: it works just calling function init() { ... }

Comment: If the typo is in your posted code, you should tell where it was.

Answer (score 0):

```
var elements = [];

var element = { 
    container: "",
    visible: false,

    init : function(div) {
    //...
       return 'hello world';
    }
};

function initialize() {
    elements.push(element.init("mydiv")); //was a typing error 
}
```

your object definition and `function initialize()` pushes just `["hello world"]` to `elements` or the function who is given, **not** the entire `var element= {...}` object.

**and additional workout**

```
    $(window).load(function() {
        //initialize();
        console.log('window call');
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //initialize();
        console.log('document call');
    });
```

fires..

**first:**  `'document call'` **second:** `'window call'`